# Update query take too long to update huge data in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to to update 100000+ rows data from another table but it takes too long more then 120 min is there any way to make this process fast

**What i am doing**

I have two table

```
+-----------------+         +-----------------------------+
|      tags       |         |            items            | 
+-----------------+         +-----------------------------+
|id | unq | name  |         |id | tag_id  | unq | detail  |
+-----------------+         +-----------------------------+
| 1 | n1  | Name1 |         | 1 |         | n2  | detail2 |
| 2 | n2  | Name2 |         | 2 |         | n1  | detail1 |
| 3 | n3  | Name3 |         | 3 |         | n3  | detail3 |
| 4 | n4  | Name4 |         | 4 |         | n8  | detail8 |
| 5 | n5  | Name5 |         | 5 |         | n4  | detail4 |
| 6 | n6  | Name6 |         | 6 |         | n5  | detail5 |
| 7 | n7  | Name7 |         | 7 |         | n9  | detail9 |
| 8 | n8  | Name8 |         | 8 |         | n6  | detail6 |
|...| ... |  ...  |         |...|         | ... | ...     |
+-----------------+         +-----------------------------+
```

I have to update `tag_id` in items table behalf of `unq` column

**These queries i used**

```
Query 1.

UPDATE `items` 
INNER JOIN tags ON (tags.unq = items.unq) 
SET items.tag_id = tags.id

-- -------------- and ---------------------

Query 2.

UPDATE `items` SET `tag_id`= (SELECT tags.id FROM tags WHERE tags.unq = items.unq Limit 1
```

Both queries i used they are taking too much time

**Output i want**

```
+-----------------------------+
|            items            |
+-----------------------------+
|id | tag_id  | unq | detail  |
+-----------------------------+
| 1 |    2    | n2  | detail2 |
| 2 |    1    | n1  | detail1 |
| 3 |    3    | n3  | detail3 |
| 4 |    8    | n8  | detail8 |
| 5 |    4    | n4  | detail4 |
| 6 |    5    | n5  | detail5 |
| 7 |    9    | n9  | detail9 |
| 8 |    6    | n6  | detail6 |
|...|   ...   | ... |   ...   |
+-----------------------------+
```

Comment: Can you pls share the explain output for the update to see how MySQL uses indexes (if any) in the update?

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following trick within single transaction: 
1.

```
RENAME items to items_old
```

2. Create new table containing joined information

`CREATE TABLE items_temp AS` 
`SELECT items.id as 'id', tags.id as 'tag_id',` 
`items.unq as 'unq', items.detail as 'detail'` 
`FROM tags INNER JOIN items ON tags.unq = items.unq`

If you need,
you may add autoinc field

```
ALTER TABLE items MODIFY COLUMN id INT auto_increment
```

3. `RENAME items_temp to items`
4. `DELETE items_old`

Answer (score 0):

The `LOAD DATA INFILE` statement reads rows from a text file into a table at a very high speed.

You can `SELECT` data and write them into a file and then load the data to another table via this method.

For more information check the [Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html).